# Insertion of date by hibernate in Postgresql

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, date, hbm

I have the following mapping for the birth date in the hbm.xml file

```
    <property name="birthDate" type="date">
    <column name="birth_date" length="4" />
    </property>>
```

The name/type of the column in the Postgresql database are:
birth_date|date
Once in a while the date is inserted incorrectly – it is about 0.03% cases, the result is a strange date, i.e. a 2456 year
What can be a reason? I suspect the column length of 4 in the hbm.xml file maybe not enough – not sure.

The hibernate version is 3.1

Comment: Probably you are passing a String that contains only a 2-digit year and the implicit conversion then gets confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrect blaming the problem on Hibernate.  The problem was in SimpleDateFormat.  Someone before me specified a static class object of this class.  In the multithreaded environment this resulted in incorrect Date formatting before using by Hibernate

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to hibernate, Keep the declarations as simple as possible. So, if you want to add a `Date` Object in the mapping use the  below code.

In the maaping file,

```
<property column="CREATED_DATE" name="createdDate" />
```

In java class,

```
java.lang.util.Date createdDate
//getters & setters
```

Once it is stable and working, you can start playing around with more options in the mapping.